# How to check if the mouse is off the page?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have tried with the following code:

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
    var mouseY = 0;
    var topValue = 0;
    window.addEventListener("mouseout", function (e) {
        mouseY = e.clientY;
        if(mouseY < topValue) {
            console.log("Out!!!");
        }
    }, false);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<datalist id="emails"><option value="example@example.com" /></datalist>
<input type="email" id="email" autocomplete='on' list="emails" required />
```

And it worked. So far so good. But I have an email `input`, and when using browser autocomplete the alert pops up when hovering over the autocomplete options, and I don't want that to happen.

How do I edit this function to identify when the cursor is off the page but does not interfere with `input` autocompletion?

Comment: Can you elaborate on the relationship between the email input and the browser autocomplete?

Comment: it's just an email input `<input type="email" id="email"
       autocomplete='on' required>`, autocomplete suggestions are from the browser itself, which have been enabled. Here is about https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Attributes/autocomplete

Comment: you can simply `autocomplete='off'` in your form tag, so that it doesn't interfere it.

Comment: but I want it to be active. it's important for me

Comment: what do you mean by browser autocomplete ?

Comment: I've moved your code into a snippet that demonstrates the issue. However this seems browser specific, since the issue isn't present when I ran the snippet in Chrome. When using Firefox it does occur.